# Extracting places from Google Maps into Excel sheet

Tags: google-maps, extract

How can I extract places from Google Maps into Excel sheet?

Answer (score 2):

Put your cursor in Google Maps on the exact point whose coordinates you want. Right click on it. This will show a whole lot of things but the top one is its location. Move your cursor and click on this and a message will appear at the bottom of the screen saying `copied to clipboard`.

Go to where you want and click <kbd>CRTL+V</kbd> for paste. The coordinate is written from the clipboard in the format "Latitude,Longitude". If you put this into Excel it will go as a text string into one cell. A better trick is to put a list of them into Word, then do a global replacement of "`,`" with the TAB character ("`^t`" in word parlance). The when you copy into Excel the latitude and longitude will be in separate cells. Alternatively, you can use Excel's string search function to copy all the text in front of the comma to one field and all the text after the comma to another. Both work just fine.

Comment: Is there a particular reason this straightforward question has been closed?